# Check and Execute a stored proc

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to check if a stored procedure exists and then I need to execute it. I am getting error in the if part when I try this:

```
use [ST_Analysis]
GO
/***** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[sp_CleanRelogTables]  
INPUT PARAMETERS
none
*****/
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT  name FROM sysobjects WHERE name = 'sp_CleanRelogTables' 
              AND type = 'P')
begin
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_CleanRelogTables]
    AS
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON
        TRUNCATE TABLE COUNTERDATA
        TRUNCATE TABLE COUNTERDETAILS
        SET NOCOUNT OFF
    END
end
Else
    execute sp_CleanRelogTables
```

Comment: Never mind. This worked.

IF NOT EXISTS(
 SELECT name 
 FROM  sysobjects 
 WHERE   name = 'sp_CleanRelogTables' 
 AND  type = 'P')
 EXEC('
 CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_CleanRelogTables]
 AS
 

 SET NOCOUNT ON
 TRUNCATE TABLE COUNTERDATA
 TRUNCATE TABLE COUNTERDETAILS
 SET NOCOUNT OFF
')
execute sp_Cleanrelogtables

Comment: can you explain why it could not execute it without dynamic query?

Comment: What is the error you are getting ?